# Twitter digits is not initialized in web

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-digits

I am using the Twitter Digits own elements in a portal to allow users to enable Twitter Digits two-factor authentication. The setup I have is exactly the same as the sample they provide: 
https://docs.fabric.io/web/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html

The first time everything works fine. However if from the menu you navigate to a different page and then get back to the twitter digits page or refresh page I am getting the following error in the console

`Error: Digits is not initialized
    at new e (cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js:1)
    at Object.logIn (cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js:1)`

below is my digit init code

`$('#digits-sdk').load(function () {
        Digits.init({ consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' })
    });`

[image]